# Vertically aligning text in a Button

Tags: css

Is there a way to center the "+" and "-" font inside my buttons?
You can see that the "-" font is not vertically aligned in the center of the button. The only solution I could think of is adding an image icon of a "+" or "-" instead of using the a button but I would prefer to have a button font.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but in this particular case you could add `padding-bottom: 0.2em;` to that button's CSS as a workaround (fine-tune that value according to the used font).

Answer (score 0):

you can add those tags to the button style

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
```

it makes everything in a center vertically